# Update executable file with new lib file without recompile

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries, static-linking

I have an executable file (foo.exe) with one library which has been linked statically.
I updated this library. Is there any way to update exe file with the updated library without need to recompile the executable file. I do not have access to the source code of the executable.
Executable and lib files written using Visual C++ 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The executable doesn't store information about which libraries were compiled statically into it, nor has it symbol tables which are necessary for linker.

Well, theoretically, if you are not afraid of reverse engineering and patching the executable in its binary format, you can try to locate the old library code in the disassembler of the .exe and carefully change the .exe so that it executes code from the new library. But it's a very hard and fragile thing to do even if the library has only a couple of functions, and it's in fact of the same complexity as decompilation of the executable and recovering its sources.

So, while there is a theoretical possibility to replace a static lib (and, in fact, to replace anything you want), it looks a very unreasonable thing to do.